# Cannot find ObjectMapper from jackson-databind maven eclipse

Tags: java, maven, jackson

In pom.xml I have:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.8.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When doing right-click on the project -> Run As -> Maven install, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile 
(default-compile) 
on project GPS: Fatal error compiling java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     
com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper:   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper -> [Help 1]
```

Other solutions says that jackson-databind.jar is missing, but I've got it in my dependencies and in the .classpath.

Comment: Why do you have two `<dependencies>` blocks?

Comment: You should probably show more pom.xml and more code.